# Cuda Finding Equal Substrings

Tags: cuda, substring

The function compute_kmers tries to find how many times a substring **kmer** occurs in string **reference_string**, **k** is the lengh of kmer.
This works on very small inputs, but on large one it finds different and wrong results. Can't sure what I am doing wrong.

```
__device__ void compare_elements(char *ref, char *kmer, int k, int *hits, int current)
{
    int equal = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        if(kmer[i] != ref[i])
        {
            equal =0;
        }
    }
    if(equal == 1)
    {

        hits[current]++;
    }

}

__global__ void compute(char *d_reference_str, char *d_kmer, int reference_length, int k, int *hits)
{


    int current = blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x;

    if(current+k<reference_length)
    {
        char *refsubstr = (char *) malloc(k * sizeof(char));
        for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
        {
            refsubstr[i] = d_reference_str[current+i];
        }
        compare_elements(refsubstr, d_kmer, k, hits, current); 
    }
}

__host__ void compute_kmers(char* reference_str, char* kmer, int reference_length, int k, int *hits)
{
    char *d_reference_str;
    char *d_kmer;
    int *d_hits;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_reference_str, reference_length*sizeof(char));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_kmer, k*sizeof(char));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_hits, MAX_REF_LENGTH * sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(d_reference_str, 
    reference_str,reference_length*sizeof(char),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_kmer, kmer,k*sizeof(char),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    int numOfBlocks=(reference_length/1024)+1;
    dim3 dimGrid(numOfBlocks, 1);
    dim3 dimBlock(1024, 1);
    compute<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_reference_str,d_kmer,reference_length, k, d_hits);

    cudaMemcpy(hits, d_hits, reference_length*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_reference_str);
    cudaFree(d_kmer);
    cudaFree(d_hits);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use dynamic memory allocation within a kernel, you should verify that the returned pointer is not null. malloc returns null if the request cannot be fulfilled.

The device-side heap is limited in size. It can be increased via `cudaDeviceSetLimit`

However, you do not need to make a copy of the reference substring. It is possible to use the reference directly instead.

```
__global__ void compute(char *d_reference_str, char *d_kmer, int reference_length, int k, int *hits)
{


    int current = blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x;

    if(current+k<reference_length)
    {
        compare_elements(d_reference_str + current, d_kmer, k, hits, current); 
    }
}
```